# How to use decltype in std::future?

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code, how can I use `decltype` in `std::future` to deduce the return type of `bar()` ? Although directly using `std::future<int>` works, I would like to know how can `decltype` be used in such a situation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>


int bar(int a)
{
    return 50;
}
int main()
{

    std::packaged_task<decltype(bar)> task(bar);

    //std::future<decltype(bar(int))> f = task.get_future(); //doesn't work need to do something like this

    std::future<int> f = task.get_future();   //works

    std::thread t1(std::move(task), 10);
    t1.detach();
    int val = f.get();
    std::cout << val << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Also, is the use of `decltype` in `std::packaged_task` correct ?

Comment: I think you mean something like `decltype(bar(0))`?

Comment: Is passing the parameter explicitly the only solution ?

Comment: @bornfree - What's the problem with that? Do you not know the parameter's value or type?

Comment: @bornfree In addition to StoryTeller's comment, in case you can't construct a parameter of the appropriate type, you can use `std::declval<T>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can use `auto`:

```
auto f = task.get_future();
```

And everything works as expected.

---

`decltype` is used to detect the type of an expression. In this case, `bar(int)` is not a valid expression. You may use `decltype(bar(0))`.

Alternatively, you can use the dedicated tools for determining the result of a function invocation. Since you tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can use `typename std::result_of<decltype(bar)*(int)>::type` (of course, you need to `#include <type_traits>`).

---

For the benefit of future readers: I would like to address this question in the perspective of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). `result_of` is expects template argument of the form `F(Args...)`, which suffers since the function type is the return type and is extremely limited. In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), `invoke_result` is introduced, and is way better than `result_of`: `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(bar), int>`. Very intuitive.